# Producing a Steerable Filter in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, signal-processing

Per my understanding, a steerable filter is a filter that essentially takes a derivative at an orientation of the image and can be used to detect edges at horizontal/vertical or any angle really.  I've tried to implement one in Matlab by first passing the image through a Gaussian Filter and then a sobel operator.

```
I = imread('Jamaica.png');
if size(I,3)==3
    I = rgb2gray(I);
end
I = imgaussfilt(I, 2);
I1 = double(I);
%grad = imgradient(I1);
%theta = [0:15:180];
%[grad_mag, grad_dir] = imgradient(I);
Ix =  [1 2 1; 0 0 0; -1 -2 -1];%Sobel horizontal edge kernel;
Iy =  [1 0 -1; 2 0 -2; 1 0 -1];%Sobel vertical edge kernel;
theta = 45;
I_theta = Ix*cos(theta) + Iy*sin(theta);
final = conv2(I1,I_theta,'same');
subplot(1,2,1); imshow(I);
subplot(1,2,2); imshow(final);
```

Using the above code I do get an image with edges, but was looking for feedback if this implementation is truly that of a steerable filter or if it can be improved

Comment: This is almost right! If you first compute the convolution with `Ix` and with `Iy` separately, you can then combine the two results with an element-wise dot product with a unit vector at an arbitrary angle. Like `Ix*cos(theta) + Iy*sin(theta)` but using the results of the two convolutions. The idea is that you do the 2 convolutions, then you can derive the result for the filter at many different angles, or even at a different angle for each pixel in the image.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I was able to do so and I can see your point about how much more flexible it is.